# Defining a custom TransactionInterceptor in Spring. And why/how bean overridding works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

### What I want to achieve

My objective is to have a transactional bean, instantiated twice (or more), and each time w/ a different `TransactionManager` (i.e. a different DB).

```java
@Transactional
class MyReusableService {
...
}

@Configuration
class MyConfig {

  // here I want to use `transactionManagerForDb1`
  @Bean
  public MyReusableService myReusableServiceForDb1() { ... }

  // here I want to use `transactionManagerForDb2`
  @Bean
  public MyReusableService myReusableServiceForDb2() { ... }
}
```

### What I observed

[TransactionInterceptor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.java) is the piece that delegates to a `TransactionManager` (TM). I found it used in 2 ways:

1. Via `@EnableJpaRepositories(... transactionManagerRef="...")`. This mechanism relates a bit w/ what I want. But it doesn't use `@Transactional` at all. It finds all the repos. And it instantiates one `TransactionInterceptor` per repo.
2. Via `@Transactional`. Here, there is a single instance of `TransactionInterceptor` (TI). And at each invocation, it decides which TM to use by looking at the annotations (using caching of course). This TI is defined [ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.java).

### What I did

I defined my own TI:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class MyTransactionInterceptor extends TransactionInterceptor {
        ...
    }
    
    @Bean
    public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(TransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource) {
        TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new MyTransactionInterceptor();
        interceptor.setTransactionAttributeSource(transactionAttributeSource);
        return interceptor;
    }
    
}
```

This seem to work. The TI defined by Spring is no more instantiated. Mine is. And it is used.

### My questions

1. Why does the above work? How did Spring know that **I wanted to override** it's TI? I was expecting to have 2 TIs, and fight to use the right one, maybe using `@Primary`. E.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398778/spring-framework-and-overridding-default-bean).
2. Is there maybe a cleaner way to achieve my objective? I cannot say I'm entirely satisfied, because I find the solution a bit intrusive. `MyReusableService` resides actually in a lib. And forcing the user to override the TI is not self contained.

Comment: I dont know about transactioninterceptor overriding but I made similar thing with creating new transaction manager. But imho transactioninterceptor update transaction data from thread local so when you create a different interceptor, you can simple use new transaction

Comment: In my app I already have 3 TransactionManagers (I have 3DBs). When Spring detects that you define a TA => it doesn't define the default one any more. You are right that this "overriding" is a bit similar. I never looked how it's done. But I think it's done w/ Conditional... in the Configuration. But here it's not the case, as we can see in ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.